# Deleted folder comes back

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, delete, trash

I am on ubuntu 18.04.

I have a folder (self-created project for website), that is locked.

Only root has access to create and delete.

I did following on folder:

- sudo chmod 777 on folder to release the lock (that worked)
- then put folder in trash and empty trash with `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` (that worked)

2 minutes later the folder is back where it was... :(

I even tried removing it with nautilus (root access), put in trash, empty trash (all worked), and again 2 minutes later the folder reappeared.

What to do?

Update: Yes, it could be because of the nodejs framework recreating it, if so, how to stop it?

Comment: Which folder? May it be recreated by the website framework?

Comment: Should have comment perms now we upvoted you. Delete your answer below.

Comment: If it is your framework or some application recreating it, you have to figure out where in the code that happens, and modify that part. It's also a fair chance there's a good reason why it gets created. What is the name of the folder?

Comment: @vidarlo Sounds like a bug. If the folder gets deleted it should not be magically recreated by the system for any reason; it was deleted. I'm also having this same problem on Ubuntu 22.04. It's very annoying.

Comment: @ChefPharaoh It depends. If it's intentional behavior then it's not a bug, even though the reasons for the behavior may be unknown to you.

Comment: @vidarlo That doesn't make sense. If the behaviour is not known to me and it's affecting me as a user then the design and implementation needs better thought. So then that would be a design bug.

Comment: @ChefPharaoh I would *not* consider it a bug if a website framework re-creates a required folder...

Answer (score 0):

Please try doing

1. Type: `sudo su`[this will ask you to enter the login password]
2. Once password entered
3. write this command: `chmod a+rwx folder/file` [copy the parent location from properties then /folder name(which is locked)]

Now, go to home and just delete the folder/file.

Exit for root user type `exit`.